# Equality of ImageData objects with Jasmine

Tags: javascript, jasmine

I want to test two `ImageData` objects for equality with Jasmine. The problem is, that the image dimensions are completely ignored in the comparison. What am I missing?

```js
var img = new Uint8ClampedArray([138, 162, 148 255, 70, 29, 70, 20 0, 0, 0, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 46, 46, 46, 17, 139, 139, 139, 255]);
var imgA = new ImageData(img, 3, 2);
var imgB = new ImageData(img, 2, 3);

expect(imgA).toEqual(imgB);
done();

//SUCCESS
```

Answer (score 0):

Write a [custom comparison](https://jasmine.github.io/2.0/custom_equality.html) so that it checks what you want it to check. In your case, you can use something like

```
  // comparator; note: untested code
  const imageEquality = (first, second) => {
    if (first.constructor == ImageData && second.constructor == ImageData) {
      return first.height == second.height
          && first.width == second.width
          && first.data.every((e,i) => e == second.data[i]));
    }
    return undefined; // we do not know how to compare that
  };

  // register to ensure that it is used in comparations
  beforeEach(function() {
    jasmine.addCustomEqualityTester(imageEquality);
  });
```